# How to customize tabs in appbar?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app, in home screen i have tabs( each tab is showing a category) and by click one of them the category products will appear.

Just like that[image]

The problem is when i click home first i must have a general products from all categories and no category should be selected first.

After the user  see's the general products he can then choose category he wants to see.

So i must customize the tabs and i don't know how.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo widget  using [DefaultTabController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DefaultTabController-class.html), you can archive it easily.

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
            floatHeaderSlivers: true,
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
                  SliverAppBar(
                    snap: true,
                    floating: true,
                    toolbarHeight: 80,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    title: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      child: Text("search here"),
                    ),
                    centerTitle: true,
                    bottom: PreferredSize(
                      preferredSize: Size(0.0, 48.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TabBar(
                            isScrollable: true,
                            indicatorWeight: 1,
                            labelColor: Colors.green,
                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                            // indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                            tabs: [
                              Tab(text: "screen1"),
                              Tab(text: "screen2"),
                              Tab(text: "screen3"),
                              Tab(text: "screen4"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text("screen1"),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text("screen2"),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text("screen3"),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text("screen4"),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did the same here. the problem is I need additional value, a value when the enter the home screen not any tab is selected and it will show general products from all categories. so the classic tabs will not work here. hope you understand.